# asp.net mvc output cache, problem in trailing "/" character

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

Iam using  to cache my asp.net mvc pages

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "something", Duration = 1800, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public ActionResult MyPage()
{

}
```

problem is cached page is not picked up when some one adds a  trailing slash character("/")

```
eg:

//cache entry 1
mySite/MyPage 

//cache entry2
mySite/MyPage/
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge it's not good to have one page accessible via many different URL's. So you could make you application to redirect when it encounters trailing slash.